# Three.js how to add multiple Mixamo animations without skin to an FBX model?

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, blender, mixamo

I'm trying to create a game where there is an animated character that has multiple animations from Mixamo. I want the animation to change based on what the user is doing on the game, like `Walking`, `Running`, or `Idle`. Here is how I'm loading the `FBX` model (without animations):

```js
loader.load('Assets/Animations/Main.fbx', function(object){
    object.traverse(function (child){
        if (child.isMesh) {
           child.castShadow = true;
           child.receiveShadow = true;
           child.frustumCulled = false;
        }
   });

   object.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2
   object.position.x = 11;
   scene.add(object);
});
```

I also have the following files, which are animations *without skin.*

```
Idle.fbx
Walking.fbx
Running.fbx
```

My goal is to try to make something like [this](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=animation#webgl_animation_skinning_additive_blending) or like [this](https://sbcode.net/threejs/fbx-animation/). The only problem with these 2 links is that in the first one, they are using a model with multiple animations attached to it (I have a plain model with 3 animations without skin), and in the second one, the code is written using `TypeScript` (I prefer `JavaScript`).

I am a newbie to 3D modelling, so I don't know how to attach all the animations without skin to the main fbx model. **How can I combine the animations to one model in Blender, or is there a way to do it in three.js?**

I appreciate any help with this, thanks!

---

### ***EDIT:***

According to @GuyNachshon, is this how I should handle this?

So first I load the model without animations (`yourMesh`), and also create an `AnimationMixer`:

```js
var mixer;

loader.load('Assets/Animations/Main.fbx', function(object){
    object.traverse(function (child){
        if (child.isMesh) {
           child.castShadow = true;
           child.receiveShadow = true;
           child.frustumCulled = false;
        }
   });

   mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(object);
   object.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2
   object.position.x = 11;
   scene.add(object);
});
```

Then, I have to load the 3 animations files without skin and add them to `animationsArray`. (Not sure if I'm loading the animations correctly...):

```js
loader.load('Assets/Animations/Idle.fbx', function(object){
    object.traverse(function (child){
        if (child.isMesh) {
           child.castShadow = true;
           child.receiveShadow = true;
           child.frustumCulled = false;
        }
   });

   object.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2
   object.position.x = 11;

   animationsArray.push(object);
   scene.add(object);
});

loader.load('Assets/Animations/Walking.fbx', function(object){
    object.traverse(function (child){
        if (child.isMesh) {
           child.castShadow = true;
           child.receiveShadow = true;
           child.frustumCulled = false;
        }
   });

   object.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2
   object.position.x = 11;

   animationsArray.push(object);
   scene.add(object);
});

loader.load('Assets/Animations/Running.fbx', function(object){
    object.traverse(function (child){
        if (child.isMesh) {
           child.castShadow = true;
           child.receiveShadow = true;
           child.frustumCulled = false;
        }
   });

   object.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2
   object.position.x = 11;

   animationsArray.push(object);
   scene.add(object);
});
```

After everything has loaded completely, I create the `actions`:

```js
let actions = mixer.clipAction(animationsArray).play();
```

But, after you say to do:

```js
actions.play();
```

What is that line going to play? Is it going to play the first animation in `animationsArray`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to create an [`AnimationMixer`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/animation/AnimationMixer).

so let's say you have created a scene, added a mesh etc. now you can init an animation mixer

```
let mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(yourMesh);
```

then to add animations use `clipActions`,

```
let actions = mixer.clipAction(animationsArray).play();
```

now play

```
actions.play();
```

but to really know how to use it you should read the docs (attached above :) )

---

##### Edit - responding to your edit

**In order to control what animation will play you can do several things, here is an example from the [docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Animation-system):**

```
const mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( mesh );
const clips = mesh.animations;

// Update the mixer on each frame
function update () {
    mixer.update( deltaSeconds );
}

// Play a specific animation
const clip = THREE.AnimationClip.findByName( clips, 'dance' );
const action = mixer.clipAction( clip );
action.play();

// Play all animations
clips.forEach( function ( clip ) {
    mixer.clipAction( clip ).play();
} );
```

**now, if you are having trouble with structuring your code, here is a general example regarding how to attach animations to fbx and control them:**

```
let mixer = THREE.AnimationMixer
let modelReady = false
const animationActions = THREE.AnimationAction
let activeAction = THREE.AnimationAction
let lastAction = THREE.AnimationAction
const fbxLoader = new FBXLoader()
```

*after we initiated everything we need, let's load everything:*

```
fbxLoader.load(
    (object) => {
        'path/to/your/model.fbx',
        object.scale.set(0.01, 0.01, 0.01)
        mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(object)

        const animationAction = mixer.clipAction(animations[0])
        animationActions.push(animationAction)
        animationsFolder.add(animations, 'default')
        activeAction = animationActions[0]  // sets current animation

        scene.add(object)  // adds animated object to your scene

        //add an animation from another file
        fbxLoader.load(
            'path/to/animation.fbx',
            (object) => {
                console.log('loaded animation')

                const animationAction = mixer.clipAction(.animations[0])
                animationActions.push(animationAction)
                animationsFolder.add(animations, 'animationName')

                //add an animation from another file
                fbxLoader.load(
                    'path/to/other/animation.fbx',
                    (object) => {
                        console.log('loaded second animation')
                        const animationAction = mixer.clipAction(animations[0])
                        animationActions.push(animationAction)
                        animationsFolder.add(animations, 'animationName')

                        //add an animation from another file
                        fbxLoader.load(
                            'path/to/animation.fbx',
                            (object) => {
                                console.log('loaded third animation');
                                const animationAction = mixer.clipAction(animations[0])
                                animationActions.push(animationAction)
                                animationsFolder.add(animations, 'animationName')

                                modelReady = true
                            },
                            (xhr) => {
                                console.log(
                                    (xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + '% loaded'
                                )
                            },
                            (error) => {
                                console.log(error)
                            }
                        )
                    },
                    (xhr) => {
                        console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + '% loaded')
                    },
                    (error) => {
                        console.log(error)
                    }
                )
            },
            (xhr) => {
                console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + '% loaded')
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error)
            }
        )
    },
    (xhr) => {
        console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + '% loaded')
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log(error)
    }
)
```

*now we should set what our animations and actions are:*

```
const animations = {
   function default() {
        setAction(animationActions[0])
    },
    function firstAnimation() {
        setAction(animationActions[1])
    },
   function sceondAnimation() {
        setAction(animationActions[2])
    },
   function thirdAnimation() {
        setAction(animationActions[3])
    }
}

const setAction = {
    if (toAction != activeAction) {
        lastAction = activeAction
        activeAction = toAction
        //lastAction.stop()
        lastAction.fadeOut(1)
        activeAction.reset()
        activeAction.fadeIn(1)
        activeAction.play()
    }
}
```

*lets animate!*

```
const clock = new THREE.Clock()

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)

    controls.update()

    if (modelReady) {mixer.update(clock.getDelta())}

    render()

}

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera)
}

animate()
```

***putting it all together:***

```js
import * as THREE from 'three'

import { FBXLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/FBXLoader'


let mixer = THREE.AnimationMixer
    let modelReady = false
    const animationActions = THREE.AnimationAction
    let activeAction = THREE.AnimationAction
    let lastAction = THREE.AnimationAction
    const fbxLoader = new FBXLoader()

fbxLoader.load(
        (object) => {
            'path/to/your/model.fbx',
            object.scale.set(0.01, 0.01, 0.01)
            mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(object)
    
            const animationAction = mixer.clipAction(animations[0])
            animationActions.push(animationAction)
            animationsFolder.add(animations, 'default')
            activeAction = animationActions[0]  // sets current animation
    
            scene.add(object)  // adds animated object to your scene
    
            //add an animation from another file
            fbxLoader.load(
                'path/to/animation.fbx',
                (object) => {
                    console.log('loaded animation')
    
                    const animationAction = mixer.clipAction(.animations[0])
                    animationActions.push(animationAction)
                    animationsFolder.add(animations, 'animationName')
    
                    //add an animation from another file
                    fbxLoader.load(
                        'path/to/other/animation.fbx',
                        (object) => {
                            console.log('loaded second animation')
                            const animationAction = mixer.clipAction(animations[0])
                            animationActions.push(animationAction)
                            animationsFolder.add(animations, 'animationName')
    
                            //add an animation from another file
                            fbxLoader.load(
                                'path/to/animation.fbx',
                                (object) => {
                                    console.log('loaded third animation');
                                    const animationAction = mixer.clipAction(animations[0])
                                    animationActions.push(animationAction)
                                    animationsFolder.add(animations, 'animationName')
    
                                    modelReady = true
                                },
                                (xhr) => {
                                    console.log(
                                        (xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + '% loaded'
                                    )
                                },
                                (error) => {
                                    console.log(error)
                                }
                            )
                        },
                        (xhr) => {
                            console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + '% loaded')
                        },
                        (error) => {
                            console.log(error)
                        }
                    )
                },
                (xhr) => {
                    console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + '% loaded')
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            )
        },
        (xhr) => {
            console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + '% loaded')
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error)
        }
    )

const animations = {
       function default() {
            setAction(animationActions[0])
        },
        function firstAnimation() {
            setAction(animationActions[1])
        },
       function sceondAnimation() {
            setAction(animationActions[2])
        },
       function thirdAnimation() {
            setAction(animationActions[3])
        }
    }
    
    const setAction = {
        if (toAction != activeAction) {
            lastAction = activeAction
            activeAction = toAction
            //lastAction.stop()
            lastAction.fadeOut(1)
            activeAction.reset()
            activeAction.fadeIn(1)
            activeAction.play()
        }
    }

const clock = new THREE.Clock()
    
    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    
        controls.update()
    
        if (modelReady) {mixer.update(clock.getDelta())}
    
        render()
    
    }
    
    function render() {
        renderer.render(scene, camera)
    }
    
    animate()
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Just to be clear, is `yourMesh` the fbx model without any animations? Other than that, what is 'animationsArray` and `action`?

Comment: `yourMesh` is your model, `animationsArray` is your animations (other fbx or glb files) in an array, and `action` should be `actions`; it's a typo. I'll correct it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still a little confused though, so I edited my question. Thanks for you help so far!

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the exact answer I was looking for!

Comment: Hey, should `THREE.AnimationAction` be `THREE.AnimationAction()`?

Comment: where? when i init?

Comment: Yeah, when you define mixer and stuff

Comment: i believe it should be without the parentheses

Comment: Great, thanks!!

Comment: Hmm... when I do `const animations = {...`, it gives me this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'default'`. What should I do about this?

Comment: you can try changing the function name, if not make sure that there are no typos in the function

Comment: Yeah, no luck… I tried copy and paste and even changed the function names but didn’t seem to help. Maybe the syntax is incorrect?

Comment: try reading this article, I believe it will explain it best :) 

https://www.dofactory.com/javascript/function-objects#:~:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20functions%20are%20called,as%20arguments%20to%20other%20functions.